# How to change two types of date format in a column to single one in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel file where there are two types of date format exists in a date column. Like:

```
1/31/10
02/01/2010
```

I want a single unique format like - MM/dd/yyyy (02/01/2010). How to achieve it? 
So far Couldn't do by using DateValue(cellID) function because of the first format (1/31/10) not supporting and also failed by formatting the whole column.

Comment: If you click the column title (A), right click, Format Cells, DATE - choose a format, does this fix it?  Does the 1/31/10 have an apostrophe (') in front to designate it as a text?

Comment: No its not working by formatting.
Secondly no the 1/31/10 doesn't has apostrophe to be designated as text.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Your real problem likely stems from how the dates got into Excel.  Especially if it came from a text or CSV file, you didn't import them correctly; so some are text, some are numeric, and some of the numerics are incorrect.  You'll need to correct that, then changing the format will be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First put this User Defined function in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function zDate(rng As Range) As Date
    Dim arr, yr As String
    arr = Split(rng.Text, "/")
    If Len(arr(2)) = 2 Then
        yr = "20" & arr(2)
    Else
        yr = arr(2)
    End If

    zDate = DateSerial(CLng(yr), CLng(arr(0)), CLng(arr(1)))
End Function
```

With data in column **A** (*assumed to be in month/day/year order*), in **B1** enter:

```
=zdate(A1)
```

and then apply the desired format to column **B**:

[image]